# Delphi XE2: Application build with runtime package with FireMonkey framework

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, runtime-packages

We can build VCL Win32 application with runtime packages (*.bpl).  These package can be loaded and unloaded dynamically or statically.

Do we have similar development option with the new FireMonkey framework in Delphi XE2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept of packages is orthognal to that of frameworks so yes, packages can be used with FMX. For example, the newly minted documentation [describes the process of creating a package for an FMX component](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Creating_a_FireMonkey_Component).